# My Wifi connection keeps dropping out Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.10

My wifi keeps dropping out at random intervals.  My computer still registers the wifi as connected, but stops sending and receiving data. and sometimes it disconnected from the router and asks for the password again and when I click on connect it says that it's wrong .. but when I turn off the wifi and then on everything is ok and the connection is normal

As requested below, the results from the "wireless script"

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 05 Feb 2020 11:11 EET +0200

Booted last: 05 Feb 2020 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.3.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:27:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:380b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0621]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:14b2 Syntek Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6455296  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
cfg80211              712704  1 wl
ideapad_laptop         20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    32768  3 ideapad_laptop,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  49152  3 ideapad_laptop,i915,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.127/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 86082sec preferred_lft 86082sec
    inet6 fe80::34df:267b:164b:8138/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Samer"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Samer' [AC1]>   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.127 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1004     1  0 09:45 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         wl
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Samer
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       6ca46cb1-8fae-440b-9df3-ffdc64e6d1d2
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     58 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.127/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1580979956
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.127
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_dhcp_server_identifier = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::34df:267b:164b:8138/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   6ca46cb1-8fae-440b-9df3-ffdc64e6d1d2 | Samer
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   7e26518f-453f-48be-bfad-ece1fac2811f | Hotspot

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID         BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 
Samer        <MAC 'Samer' [AC1]>  Infra  5     2432 MHz  270 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2       yes     *      
OrangeFiber  <MAC 'OrangeFiber' [AC2]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  130 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Samer]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Samer | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Samer
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Hotspot | type=wifi | autoconnect=false | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=michael-Lenovo-Z50-70
[ipv4] method=shared
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Nicosia (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp1s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Samer' [AC1]>
                    Channel:5
                    Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Samer"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'OrangeFiber' [AC2]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"OrangeFiber"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     00D38A27B7E3C7B97C238FC
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       5.3.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         michael-Lenovo-Z50-70 Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        6B:EF:E3:F2:FC:5F:AC:6F:36:53:85:0B:21:D9:2B:CD:3E:0C:05:AB
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      74:77:BB:86:46:4E:8E:43:10:99:48:2A:30:F6:23:C6:F5:68:26:72:
        C6:0B:E0:28:94:39:2B:0A:4D:C0:41:95:DE:EF:64:62:46:10:E6:1D:
        21:46:E0:79:1E:71:42:5A:78:92:C4:13:0E:91:22:9E:EE:B9:FD:81:
        15:EB:CD:EF:6C:CE:56:94:84:2F:1C:FE:E9:4C:43:8D:9E:D2:92:86:
        96:21:73:24:36:F8:3C:4D:33:55:DA:44:CE:DD:27:78:80:9B:CB:36:
        EF:BB:4E:8D:D1:24:6D:B1:E6:8C:53:56:49:D5:79:31:B9:14:D0:64:
        38:8E:D0:10:97:96:92:55:32:65:56:00:23:7C:58:BD:0A:CF:69:5C:
        14:25:6E:02:A7:4D:89:52:7C:CC:F1:ED:E9:F9:F0:F7:99:6E:89:44:
        05:F8:06:E5:B4:7C:68:50:78:40:D8:FD:58:30:FF:46:A6:55:F8:76:
        25:12:2D:F9:10:8C:0F:99:C6:A4:FE:C1:0E:A7:F1:10:54:55:79:9D:
        6B:92:9E:63:84:1F:D3:43:6C:00:82:5D:95:DB:D0:D8:97:C0:5C:25:
        24:F7:8F:F8:DC:09:10:47:45:10:41:44:F4:A8:FB:09:27:73:A1:C5:
        22:F6:9F:E0:AE:16:30:A2:31:07:63:6B:19:A6:02:42
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     7A4BDDDDFBDE4DDDB63AAE3
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.3.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        5B:A4:37:5A:64:28:0B:8F:ED:71:C0:A1:4B:B6:F3:76:64:5C:8D:F4
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      03:41:75:AA:CB:43:E0:42:12:96:85:79:29:8A:37:33:0E:D5:88:C7:
        59:3F:FF:38:40:51:31:C5:BD:9A:82:E1:ED:18:77:23:CA:21:00:F8:
        F4:7F:B0:F8:16:64:88:FB:24:96:8E:2B:56:A7:5E:35:8E:EB:E2:0A:
        0B:A9:24:0B:12:AB:92:2F:1C:70:5A:69:E4:27:2D:94:84:AB:A0:9E:
        33:E4:28:AB:E0:78:B9:88:FB:A2:37:2A:AC:59:2F:92:F5:37:68:8C:
        94:90:EF:8C:C2:A6:0D:59:A8:85:AB:20:47:6B:02:15:FD:82:4B:99:
        D2:3A:89:CE:7A:32:3E:07:40:C6:89:B6:19:ED:A0:B2:BB:2D:29:86:
        79:E1:5E:01:E9:5D:6F:7A:BD:15:DF:25:85:87:1C:B4:48:2C:B7:0B:
        00:4A:D0:B8:ED:D5:58:27:3F:2F:24:70:BA:76:35:4F:BE:2B:74:F4:
        98:0E:9C:5F:A0:15:4F:9C:BC:E3:33:7C:07:39:B4:08:A0:33:0E:5C:
        5D:66:1C:C6:DE:C7:21:4C:BD:44:95:EC:C5:EE:4F:52:37:C4:EF:BB:
        FF:35:47:F3:3F:1A:92:A3:0A:53:50:37:B9:52:95:F2:E9:C9:DD:0B:
        E6:26:9B:7D:7B:D5:52:04:4A:20:C4:26:E5:EC:2B:A1:46:BB:CE:04:
        A8:BD:80:7D:FB:9E:21:B6:CB:AC:CD:C3:D6:E8:97:9F:A2:AD:54:4D:
        6B:B1:F4:79:3E:44:6A:34:5B:15:6B:34:63:95:62:66:E7:37:53:9B:
        C3:B2:9F:4B:ED:05:39:3E:24:F0:08:C9:A2:65:E1:22:6C:93:1C:E7:
        C9:89:F3:05:74:D6:94:79:2A:D7:B9:CA:BC:1C:D3:C2:AF:5F:B2:C8:
        8D:E1:A1:52:0B:EA:0B:BA:51:29:53:E9:1A:84:50:67:43:0A:C3:BE:
        92:4D:54:D2:93:3F:20:68:43:AE:4D:D1:BB:78:3D:93:6B:C2:64:2F:
        DA:4F:E2:2B:89:B1:27:8C:61:7E:A8:BF:87:C8:FE:0A:37:A1:74:70:
        47:B9:74:F6:71:47:AD:AE:BF:71:C4:4B:B5:E5:E4:EE:DB:7E:67:FA:
        57:69:0F:48:43:5B:63:52:8D:0D:A1:DF:D7:95:B5:58:86:2D:40:14:
        F9:6E:BF:3A:51:4B:CE:7F:EC:60:C2:0A:3F:EB:44:DA:8B:AE:3F:C7:
        80:75:AF:88:BC:03:28:E1:00:BD:4D:76:D6:22:F9:06:24:B1:F7:DB:
        9C:7F:CC:9D:1B:6E:CA:9C:6F:5A:49:A7:F3:63:59:A6:10:DF:31:2F:
        DB:F2:98:C0:27:5A:3A:63:54:62:B2:74
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 4459.452910] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Down
[ 4464.006058] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 4832.521081] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : 

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: I have the same problem with the ntel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] using iwlwifi. I posted a question here https://redd.it/f18ghz but was told to look on this site.